# Prove that integer $n$ is divisible by $65$

Tags: divisibility

Can anybody help me with this problem?

> Prove that for every integer $n$, $$p(n) = n^{18} - n^{14} - n^6 + n^2$$ is divisible by $65$.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the source of this problem?

Comment: Yes I got to that point. But I cannot factorize the equation so that I could prove that I can divide it by 5 or 13

Comment: Please edit your question to include the source of this problem.

Comment: source? You mean book?

Comment: Presumably, you would be given this assignment if you are already familiar with Fermat's little theorem, and (probably) Euler's theorem.

Comment: yes both but the issue I am facing is that I cannot get the n^x == n(modx)... I need to somehow factorize the equation but I am not getting how

Comment: Euler's isn't actually helpful here, since $\phi(65)=48$, but all our exponents are <48. But as the answers below show, we can attack it with little Fermat & the CRT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints:**

Factor it as $n^2(n^{4}-1)(n^{12}-1)=(n^5-n)(n^{13}-n)$.

Note that $65=5\times13$.

Now use Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: Yey I got it! Thanks

Comment: Actually, you can easily use Fermat's little theorem on $$n^2(n^{16}-n^{12}-n^4+1)$$ You don't need to factorise it any further.

Comment: I used the first form and used theorem on non prime powers

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Use *lil' Fermat* and the *Chinese remainder theorem*:

- Modulo $5$, we have $n^5\equiv n$ for all $n$, hence
  $$n^{18}=n^{15}n^3=(n^5 n)^3\equiv (n^2)^3=n^6\equiv n^2 \\
  n^{14}=n^{10}n^4=(n^5n^2)^2\equiv(n^3)^2=n^6\equiv n^2\\
  \text{so that }\quad  n^{18} - n^{14} - n^6 + n^2\equiv n^2-n^2-n^2+n^2=0 \mod 5.$$
- Similarly, modulo $13$, we have $n^{13}\equiv n$ for all $n$. Can you proceed?

Comment: Yes great thanks I think I got the answer